Is it possible to design purely staless replay attack free client-server relationship?
The use case is fairly simple:
Client sends request1 to Server endpoint1. Server endpoint1 responses with response1. Then Client sends request2 to Server endpoint2. Server endpoint2 responses with response2. Then Client sends, again request1 to Server endpoint1. And this is the place where Server endpoint1 should response with error.
This is the place where cryptographic solution may come into play. Cookies, tokens etc.
So the solution I'm looking for has some requirements:

no persistence, even cache
Client is only allowed to access endpoint once
Client-Server flow is only unidirectional

Even ChatGpt didn't suggest anything useful, maybe somebody ever has came across such a problem and got a solution?
Many thanks in advance!

Does a trusted timestamps service solve your problem? If request1 includes a timestamp and response1 is tied to the timestamp, the server can deny a replay.

@DanielS trusted timestamp can be replaced by any other cookie/token, so here only data tamper check is done. Regarding timestamps, it is kind of solution, but is is not deterministic, i.e. sometimes user may succeed to reach endpoint within a given timeframe, sometimes not, it purely depends on traffic. So I guess no, it isn't a solution, unfortunately..
